# set property syntax in Powershell

Tags: iis, powershell

I am new to PowerShell, I am trying to change a property of an IIS website using the following syntax (which doesn't work)

```
(get-item 'IIS:\Sites\Default Website').logFile.directory = 'd:\'
```

It doesn't show any error but doesn't change the property either.

Anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need either:

Set `logFile` to a new value with the correct directory

or

`Set-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Website' -name ...`